# Getting records from one table not in another

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a table, called Prices composed of a few fields, two of which is *ProductId* and *PriceType*. Some products have both Wholesale price `(PriceType = W)` and Retail price `(PriceType = R)`, i.e. they have two records with the same product id.

I would like to display to the user those products with no retail price (i.e. those with only one record W).

How should I write my query to do this?

I have used something like

```
Select * from Products 
INNER JOIN Prices ON Products.Id = Prices.ProductId 
WHERE ProductId NOT IN 
  (SELECT ProductId FROM Prices WHERE PriceType="R")
```

but this is executing very slow. I have checked and verified that the part taking a long time is really the NOT IN clause.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the query in MS Access or SQL Server, that is, is it a passthrough query or a query against linked tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN Prices 
        ON Products.Id = Prices.ProductId 
       AND Prices.PriceType = 'W'
```

This will filter out the Prices at the join so you never have any `PriceType='R'` records joined.

To filter out those records that do not have an 'R' at all, you can use the following query, which removes the sub-select on your where clause

```
SELECT 
    Products.ProductId
FROM 
    Products 
    INNER JOIN Prices A
        ON Products.ProductId = A.ProductId 
        AND A.PriceType = 'W'
    LEFT JOIN Prices B
        ON A.ProductId = B.ProductId 
        AND B.PriceType <> A.PriceType    
WHERE
    A.PriceType = 'W'
    AND B.PriceId is null
```

To ensure this runs as fast as possible, ensure you add an index to your Prices table that includes both the ProductId and PriceType columns

Comment: Thanks for this, but I believe this will return all products with a wholesale price; that's all the products; I am really looking for the products with a wholesale price which do not also have a retail price.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `Left Excluding JOIN`, check [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

```
SELECT <select_list> 
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.Key IS NULL
```

so your query should be:

```
Select * from Products 
Left JOIN Prices ON Products.Id = Prices.ProductId 
Prices.ProductId IS NULL 
AND
Prices.PriceType = 'W'
```

I have not tested yet..

hope this help to implement..